# Pi loses connectivity and stops running scripts after a few hours

Tags: wifi, power, script, logfiles

After a few hours unattended, powered by a spare microUSB phone charger, my pi loses connectivity and stops running scripts, which don't depend on internet connectivity.

An example of a process/script that will stop running is a crontab call every 5 minutes to a script in /usr/local/bin that checks on an init.d process. Whenever my connectivity cuts out, so does everything it seems. In fact, the logs I've tried to throw together only report good outcomes, i.e. 'process x is running.' Whenever stuff cuts out, there is just nothing logged.

What might be happening?

I'd note I had everything working on a smaller sd card by the same manufacturer, and decided to move everything to a larger sd card.

I am connected to WiFi by on of the Edimax dongles.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a power issue. Don't go by the label on the charger to really diagnose the problem you will need a multimeter and test on the actual board. You dont't mention what model Pi you have but the link should cover it http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Comment: What is most likely cause of power problems? The charger itself?

Comment: Yes, the charger that is why I said not to trust the label and test to be sure. I had this problem and a search of this site and the web in general will show lots of problems traced back to power issues. BTW are you connected with the dashboard app cyfe?

Comment: yeah, I have one cable that sits around 4.8 V and another at 4.9 volts and that appears to make all the difference.

Comment: You should answer your own question. and accept it (I think you need to wait 2 days to accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use a different cable that averaged closer to 4.9 volts rather than 4.8 volts. No issues since finding a cable setup that worked better.